# Durandal routing not working?

Tags: single-page-application, durandal

I've got several pages up and working in my project that I can navigate to directly - one for home, another for "folder details".  I list Folders on the homepage and I'm now trying to enable navigation to particular folders from the list.

If I navigate to /set I get a default set details page, that works.

If I navigate to /set/1 I get "no route found" from my main.js:

```
router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
                logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
            };
```

What is needed to form the link between the id in the URL and the viewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing this line in my main.js:

```
router.mapNav("folder/:id");
```